# Using sparl.read.csv when one column is xml

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have CSV with 10 columns, one of which is an XML field. When I read this into a databricks notebook from azure data lake it splits up the xml into new rows, instead of keeping it in the one field.

Is there a way to stop this happening? The data looks like this when displayed

[image]

But like this when I open the CSV

[image]

I'm using the following code to read the csv

```
sourceDf = spark.read.csv(sourceFilePath, sep=',', header=True, inferSchema=True)
```

I'm attempting to build a data pipeline in ADF and want to use databricks to parse the XML field, but I need to be able to read it in to databricks first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the data correctly I needed to define multiline=True as an option as below:

```
sourceDf = spark.read.csv(sourceFilePath, sep=',', header=True, inferSchema=True, multiLine=True)
```

Then I get a correctly formatted column.